# finding low contrast edges

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

How can I find the low contrast edges in the following image:

[image]

Here are the results for the DOG detector in GIMP:

[image]

All of the algorithms I've tried (canny, sobel, laplace, dog, etc) miss the almost vertical edge in the upper right corner as well as most of the diagonal edges above the door on the lower left. I see this problem in almost every image. There are patches with an easily identifiable edge that the various edge detector miss.

Comment: try "auto-adjust image" + "detect edges"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the fault of the edge detector, it's because you need to pre-process the image to make it more suitable for edge detection. So you may wish to try histogram equalisation (a.k.a. contrast stretching) and optionally some additional smoothing (e.g. Gaussian or median filter) before runnning it through an edge detector.

Here's a couple of example outputs using your source image. First, using the RGB image and ImageJ, I just performed two steps: Enhance contrast and find edges:

[image: result 1]

Then, using GIMP, I converted the original RGB image to greyscale, performed contrast stretch, then Sobel filter:

[image: result 2]

You can see that the "best" result is "best" in the sense of what you want to do with it next, and that the preprocessing plays a significant part in the overall process.